# How to create a column in Pandas with distance from coordinates using GeoPy

Tags: python, pandas, distance, geopy

I have this df:

```
    latitude_1  longitude_1
0   -25.294871  -56.992654
1   -24.946374  -57.384543
2   -24.835273  -53.825342
3   -24.153553  -54.363844
```

And the following coordinates:

```
coords_2 = (-25.236632,  -56.835262)
```

So I want to create a 3rd column in the df that shows the distance between each row with coords_2.

If I try to do it without using Dataframes, it works (here I'm using random numbers):

```
import geopy.distance

coords_1 = (52.2296756, 21.0122287)
coords_2 = (43.263845, -42.2637377)

print(geopy.distance.distance(coords_1, coords_2).km)
```

Output:

```
4691.07078306837
```

So I want to apply this same logic to a Dataframe.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare your `df` coordinates with some external coordinates tuple, try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopy.distance

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'latitude_1': [-25.294871, -24.946374], 'longitude_1': [-56.992654, -57.384543]})
coords_2 = (-25.236632,  -56.835262)
df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda x: geopy.distance.distance((x.latitude_1, x. longitude_1), coords_2).km, axis=1)
```

```
   latitude_1  longitude_1   distance
0  -25.294871   -56.992654  17.116773
1  -24.946374   -57.384543  64.062048
```

Or with `to_numpy()`:

```
def distance(l1, l2, coords_2):
  return [geopy.distance.distance((lat, lng), coords_2).km for lat, lng in zip(l1, l2)]

df['distance'] = distance(df["latitude_1"].to_numpy(),df["longitude_1"].to_numpy(), coords_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that also without using geopandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopy
import geopy.distance


def distance_from_custom_point(row):
    start = geopy.Point(-25.236632,  -56.835262)
    end = geopy.Point(row['longitude'], row['latitude'])
    row['dist'] = geopy.distance.distance(start, end).km
    return row


df = pd.DataFrame({'latitude': [-25.294871, -24.946374, -24.835273, -24.153553],
                  'longitude': [-56.992654, -57.384543, -53.825342, -54.363844]})


df = df.apply(distance_from_custom_point, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply apply a lambda function to the existing dataframe

```
df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda x: geopy.distance.distance(x.tolist(), coords_2).km,
                          axis=1)
```

you should get:

```
   latitude_1  longitude_1    distance
0  -25.294871   -56.992654   17.116773
1  -24.946374   -57.384543   64.062048
2  -24.835273   -53.825342  306.992429
3  -24.153553   -54.363844  277.379381
```